# Property not being set

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee

I've searched for a solution for my problem and got nothing until now. I created a new Dynamic Project on Eclipse JEE. I'm trying to create a simple project: I have 3 inputText's, 2 of them are for number I want to sum, and the third one is for the result.

In my Controller I have the operation of sum that access the 2 values or properties `numA` and `numB` entered by the user.

But my problem, is the values are always null on controller. I put the setters and getters inside it, but the setters aren't being called, just the getters.

Here is my code:

index.xhtml:

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
        xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" 
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" 
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"> 

    <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="calc">
        <h:inputText id="somaNumA" value="#{calcController.numA}" />
        <h:inputText id="somaNumB" value="#{calcController.numB}"  />
        <h:inputText id="resultadoSoma" value="#{calcController.result}" />
        <h:commandButton value="Somar" id="botaoSoma" type="button"  onclick="#{calcController.soma()}" ajax="true">            
            <f:ajax execute="calc" render=":calc:resultadoSoma"  /> 
        </h:commandButton>
    </h:form>

</html>
```

Here is the Controller:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

@SessionScoped
public class CalcController implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1609040715417969082L;
    private String numA, numB, result;

    public CalcController() {}

    public String soma() {

        Integer resultInt = 0;
        if (numA != null && numB != null) {
            resultInt = Integer.parseInt(numA) + Integer.parseInt(numB);
        }

        this.result = resultInt.toString();
        //setResult("teste");
        return this.result;
    }

    public String getNumA() {
        System.out.println("get");
        return numA;
    }

    public void setNumA(String numA) {
        System.out.println("set");
        this.numA = numA;
    }

    public String getNumB() {
        return numB;
    }

    public void setNumB(String numB) {
        this.numB = numB;
    }

    public String getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult(String result) {
        this.result = result;
    }
}
```

The faces-config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <faces-config
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee           
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
        version="2.0">


    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>calcController</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>com.controller.CalcController</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope> 
    </managed-bean>
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
            xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
            xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
            id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0"> 

        <welcome-file-list> 
            <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file> 
        </welcome-file-list> 

        <!-- JSF --> 
        <servlet> 
            <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name> 
            <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class> 
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup> 
        </servlet> 

        <servlet-mapping> 
            <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name> 
            <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern> 
        </servlet-mapping> 
</web-app>
```

Does someone know where I am failing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `onclick` attribute of [`h:commandButton`](http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/html/h_commandButton.html) component sets a Javascript code to be invoked. You want to invoke a server action, therefore you have to use `action` instead. Moreover, ajax is not an attribute of `h:commandButton`, you are probably confusing with `p:commandButton` (note that the default value for attribute `ajax` is indeed `true`, so you can avoid it in any case).
Same thing in `f:ajax`: you have to pass a server action there.

```
<h:commandButton value="Somar" id="botaoSoma" action="#{calcController.soma()}" >
```

Comment: Still can't get it to work... :(
Perharps it could be a configuration in Eclipse?

Comment: See my update. If still not working, I suggest to start with a basic tutorial.

Comment: I got it!! Thanks!! But the problem was "action" had to be the first param of commandButton, I don't know why.. The code: <h:commandButton action="#{calcController.soma()}" value="Somar" id="botaoSoma"  > Now it's working! Thank you!
   
   <f:ajax execute="calc" render=":calc:resultadoSoma"  /> 
  </h:commandButton>